summation of a series on a lattice
I am a physics student. And I am working on some wave function on some lattice. One question I encountered in my study is studying the following summation
$$f(x)=\sum_{m,n \in Z}\cos((m-n)gx)\exp(-\frac{(k_x+mg)^2}{4\chi^2})\exp(-\frac{(k_x+ng)^2}{4\chi^2})\exp(-\beta g^2(m-n)^2)$$
All the variables are real $g>0$,$k_x>0$,$\chi>0$,$\beta>0$
$f(x)$ is obviously periodic in x with periodicity $\frac{2\pi}{g}$. There are two questions I have
(1) If I set $\beta=0$, then I know numerically $f(x)$ becomes more and more localized when $\chi$ becomes larger (it looks more and more like ~$\sum_n\delta(x-\frac{2\pi (n+\frac{1}{2})}{g})$). How can I study this analytically, that is can I obtain an expansion of f(x) that approaches an array of delta function at very large $\chi$?
(2) For finite $\chi$, but let me take $\beta$ to be very large, I also notice that $f(x)$ becomes less and less localized. And it is obvious that when I take $\beta$ to infinity, only $m=n$ term is left, and the function becomes completely uniform. Again, can I obtain an expansion of $f(x)$ in terms of $\beta$ that describes this process?
